# Ultrasonic thread that runs in the background in python

Tags: python, multithreading, nxt-python

How do I create a thread that continuously checks for obstacles using the ultrasonic class in nxt-python 2.2.2? I want to implement it in a way that while my robot is moving it also detects obstacles in a background process and once it detects an object it will brake and do something else

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used the daemon thread instead of normal thread. because this is different to normal thread. I hope so daemon thread resolve your problem.

Comment: it seems that when I use the turn method in the synchronized motors class it doesn't stop until the turn method finish its execution in that means even if I use my ultrasonic sensors it still moves